# Python: Identify which keys are pressed, process all the key pressed then print the result

Tags: python

I am developing a Keyboard program for visually impaired people, and it works like Perkins Brailler.

My question is:

1. How to limit the legal key pressed while the program is running
2. How to detect all the key pressed (within 0,5 sec) and directly process the key press as an input then directly print the result of the process.
   (For example, I want to translate while the key "as" or "sa" pressed simultaneously(the order does not matter) to letter "y")

Thank you

Comment: I think you are referring to accessing a (special?) keyboard device in a rather raw way.  That is below the scope of Python alone and will depend on the operating system running on the computer your device is attached to.  Please provide more information about the periphery of your keyboard.

Comment: Hi Alfe, thank you for the reply. I am not trying to access special keyboard. I am trying to make a program which translate braille characters to alphabetical characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can see which keys are currently being pressed using the pygame.key.get_pressed() method. It returns a list of boolean values on which keys are currently being pressed.

```
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    A, S, D = keys[K_a], keys[K_s], keys[K_d] # add right hand dots as well
    braille_dict = {'a': D, 'b': D and S,} # and so on for every combination
```

You'll need to then check for each combination of keystrokes to make the different braille letters by using the logical 'and' operator. So if 2 keys are being pressed at the same time, it might make a different braille letter than the 2 being pressed one after the other. Once you see which combination is being pressed, you can then print it

You can't limit the keystrokes that one is typing, but you can ignore the ones that the program does not require (keys apart from the home row?).

Comment: why do I get "pygame.error: video system not initialized" error?

Comment: @Michael Because you did/called something, probably `pygame.init()` and the video system could not be initialized.

Comment: Yes. You need to call pygame.init() before. You can read up on the documentation a bit [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/)